# Remove next line from Json

Tags: java, json, newline

I have a JSON string with the following structure

```
[
    {
        "id": "77897",
        "locid": "44",
        "areaid": "1465",
        "name": "Nandilath Electronics",
        "address": "G B Road, Palakkad HO, Palakkad - 678001 <--
-->8129807901, 8129807902",
        "phone": "049122545926,9895942222",
        "website": "",
        "email": "",
        "latitude": "10.9344568",
        "longitude": "76.9503265999999",
        "image": "",
        "description": ""
    },
    {
```

I need to remove the newline from here and add a comma (,) there for the string to work properly. I tried many methods and failed so please help me.

Comment: where is the next line in this string?

Comment: Replacing a newline character (is this what you mean with "nextline"?) with a comma shouldn't be that hard. What did you try? What's the exact problem?

Comment: I've marked it with the <-- the whole data should be coming in a single line but its not, that's the problem

Comment: tried removing the spaces and '\\n' but that didn't help

Comment: are the other parameters separated also with nextline characters or is just the one signalling the only nextline character in the whole string?

Comment: there are multiple occurrences but its not common..

Answer (score 1):

```
    String json="[ { \"id\": \"77897\", \"locid\": \"44\", \"areaid\": \"1465\", \"name\": \"Nandilath Electronics\", \"address\": \"G B Road, Palakkad HO, Palakkad - 678001\n8129807901, 8129807902\", \"phone\": \"049122545926,9895942222\", \"website\": \"\", \"email\": \"\", \"latitude\": \"10.9344568\", \"longitude\": \"76.9503265999999\", \"image\": \"\", \"description\": \"\" }, { ";
    json=json.replace("\n",",");
    System.out.println(json);
```

Did the work.

May be you have forgot to assign the returned value of `replace()` method to the string. Note that the `replace()` method will not change the string on which it is called.

Comment: Ya about that... I'm using Blackberry Java plugin and replace method only takes characters in that not string and that didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

ok I've found a solution, I'm using the ascii value of the newline(nextline whatever) and replacing it with a the ascii value of comma(,).
Anyways thanks for the help all.